# docker playground: no space left on device in default browser

Tags: docker, tomcat, memory, browser, docker-run

`docker command`

```
$ docker run -d --rm -p 8888:8080 tomcat:9.0
```

When I use my default browser, I get the error `no space left on device`.
when I use other browser with different docker account, It works.

```
$ docker ps
```

[image]

**Is the issue with the browser or my docker account?**

Comment: Please provide additional information like where is the docker running, where is the browser, etc.

Comment: Also, please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information (including the additional info) in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask].

Comment: Account, probably. Try `docker system prune -af`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear cache and wait for some time before you start again (could take long). This issue happens most of the time as the issue occurs when using multiple instances of docker playground that is opening multiple tabs.